# Density related to sparseness measure

Tags: distributions, multivariate-analysis, density-function, continuous-data, non-negative-matrix-factorization

Are there any multi-variate continuous distributions whose probability distribution functions give high values for sparse vectors and low values for dense vectors, i. e. indicating the sparseness of the vector?

I found one sparseness measure in [1] which is as follows for $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$:

$$s(x) = \frac{\sqrt{n}-\frac{\sum |x_i|}{\sqrt{\sum x_i^2}}}{\sqrt{n}-1}$$

It gives 1 if the vector has only one non-zero element and 0 if all the elements are equal as given below (the image is from the referenced paper).

[image: Sparseness values]

This seems to be a good candidate for a *potential* instead of a *density* and it helps in my case since I compute the likelihood on the given data.

I wonder if there exists any known distributions which can be used in this case. And how can I generate random vectors belonging to that distribution?

[1] [P. O. Hoyer, *Non-negative matrix factorization with sparseness constraints*,
Journal of Machine Learning Research, vol. 5, pp. 1457–1469, 2004](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/v5/hoyer04a.html).